# Formulations of Generalized Eigenvalue Decompositions

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let there be two matrices $A$ and $B \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$, and their generalized Eigenvalue Decomposition $A X = \Lambda BX$, where $X$ contains the generalized Eigenvectors of the pencil {$A,B$} and $\Lambda$ contains their corresponding generalized eigenvalues. However, I found another definition in the literature that goes $AX = BX\Lambda $. Are those definitions equivalent?

Comment: What are the dimensions of $X$ and $\Lambda$?